# Insert multiple checkbox value from android using json string into mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wish to insert values from `mutiple checkboxes` into mysql database using php but the code does not work. The plan is to send the checkbox values as `json string` and insert each value on a `separate row` using php.
I have `empty` table even after ticking a checkbox and submitting. Below is my code.

```
<?php

         if (isset($_POST)){


        include("config.php");


        $name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

        $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email_address']);

        $id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['code']);

        $category = $_POST['speciality']; //this is the json string..example [{"a": "1", "b" : "2"}]

        $data = json_decode($category,true);

        $pass = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $hashed_password =  password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        if(($id === "hello") || ($id === "hiii")){


            foreach($data as $fields){
                foreach($fields as $key => $val){

                $query1 = "INSERT INTO category(email,cat_id) VALUES('$email', '$val')";
                $result1 = $conn->query($query1);
                }
            }
            if ( $result1) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO friend(name,email,pass) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$hashed_password')";
                    $result = $conn->query($query);

                    if ( $result){

                        echo "success";
                    }
                    else {
                    echo "fail";
                    } 
            }    
        }
        else{

          echo "id_mismatch";
        }

     }



?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: While it's good that you're making an effort to properly hash your passwords, you're hashing the escaped version, which is wrong. You should be escaping the hash.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: `print_r($data);` also need to see the form.

Comment: Well noted @ tadman..will work on it please

Comment: Other post works fine for me except the json data.

Comment: @ AbraCadaver, `print_r($data)` outputs `Array ( [0] => Array ( [bananna] => 1 [orange] => 2 [pawpaw] => 3 [mango] => 4 ) )`

Comment: It is a android form with chekboxes included